# How to pass values dynamically to SQL script

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have following table as mentioned below and total number of fields in table are : `5` `->` `[ id,name,surname,age,country ]` and this 5 fields will be loaded with data from csv file

**My Oracle table structure :**

```
create table test
(
    id number,
    name varchar2(50 char),
    surname varchar2(50 char),
    age number,
    country varchar2(50 char)
)
```

**The data in file is mentioned below :**

```
1|Fred|Nurke|21|UK
2|Henry|Crun|24|US
3|FSD|Nue|22|BA
4|Hen|Cn|25|MA
```

**Issue :** This following line in below script I want to make it dynamic : `data.append((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]))`

For now this line is taking 5 parameter , which are nothing but column fields names

```
id - > line[0]
name -> line[1]
surname -> line[2]
age -> line[3]
country -> line[4]
```

Incase I have another table and which as different structure with 8 field ,then i need to re-write the script and replace the following line with this : `data.append((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4] , line[5], line[6] ,line[7]))`

Their is any way like take the entire line as string and pass it to the script like below

```
my_field ='line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4] , line[5], line[6] ,line[7]'

data.append((my_field))
```

Below code is not working and throwing syntax error : `data.append((my_field))`

Do i need to enclose within single quote : `data.append(('my_field'))`

**SQL script to insert data to table :**

```
import logging
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import sys
import os

insertQuery = "insert into test (id,name,surname,age,country) values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)"
oracleconnection = 'un/pw@localhost/orclpdb1'
my_separator = '|'
file_name = 'demo_2021.csv'
my_field = 'line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]'
set_inputsizes_value = 'None, 50, 50, None, 50'

def insertdata(oracleconnection, file_name, my_separator, insertQuery, my_field,set_inputsizes_value):
    
    if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME") + "/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")
    
    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(oracleconnection)
        cur = con.cursor()
        
        # Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
        cur.setinputsizes(set_inputsizes_value)
        
        # Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
        batch_size = 10000
        
        with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=my_separator)
            data = []
            for line in csv_reader:
                data.append((my_field))
                if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
                    cur.executemany(sql, data)
                    data = []
                    if data:
                        cur.executemany(insertQuery, data)
                        con.commit()
    except Exception as er:
        print(er)

insertdata(oracleconnection, file_name, my_separator, insertQuery, my_field,set_inputsizes_value)
```

Comment: You can do `data.append(line)`: `cursor.execute` will accept a list as well as a tuple.  A tuple is the data structure conventionally used for passing values to a query but any sequence type will work (though strings will generally do the wrong thing, and the ordering of sets is not reliable).

Comment: @snakecharmerb can you show with sample example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example (we have 2 list with different size lists) :

```
my_field_01 = ['one','two','three', 'four']
my_field_02 = ['one','two','three', 'four','five','six']
```

First case (my_field_01 => 4 items) :

```
data=[]
data.append([i for i in my_field_01])
print(data)

# Output:
[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
```

Second case,(my_field_02 => 6 items):

```
data=[]
data.append([i for i in my_field_02])
print(data)

# Output:
[['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

For your specific case, you can do something like this:

```
        for line in csv_reader:
            data.append([i for i in line])
```